# Resampling boolean values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, pandas-resample

I have run into a property which I find peculiar about resampling Booleans in `pandas`.  Here is some time series data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020 5:00', periods=10, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Bools':[True,True,False,False,False,True,True,np.nan,np.nan,False],
                   "Nums":range(10)},
                  index=dr)
```

So the data look like:

```
                     Bools  Nums
2020-01-01 05:00:00   True     0
2020-01-01 06:00:00   True     1
2020-01-01 07:00:00  False     2
2020-01-01 08:00:00  False     3
2020-01-01 09:00:00  False     4
2020-01-01 10:00:00   True     5
2020-01-01 11:00:00   True     6
2020-01-01 12:00:00    NaN     7
2020-01-01 13:00:00    NaN     8
2020-01-01 14:00:00  False     9
```

I would have thought I could do simple operations (like a sum) on the boolean column when resampling, but  (as is) this fails:

```
>>> df.resample('5H').sum()

                    Nums
2020-01-01 05:00:00    10
2020-01-01 10:00:00    35
```

The "Bools" column is dropped.  My impression of why this happens was b/c the `dtype` of the column is `object`.  Changing that remedies the issue:

```
>>> r = df.resample('5H')
>>> copy = df.copy() #just doing this to preserve df for the example
>>> copy['Bools'] = copy['Bools'].astype(float)
>>> copy.resample('5H').sum()

                     Bools  Nums
2020-01-01 05:00:00    2.0    10
2020-01-01 10:00:00    2.0    35
```

But (oddly) you *can* still sum the Booleans by indexing the resample object without changing the `dtype`:

```
>>> r = df.resample('5H')
>>> r['Bools'].sum()

2020-01-01 05:00:00    2
2020-01-01 10:00:00    2
Freq: 5H, Name: Bools, dtype: int64
```

And also if the only column is the Booleans, you can still resample (despite the column still being `object`):

```
>>> df.drop(['Nums'],axis=1).resample('5H').sum()

                    Bools
2020-01-01 05:00:00      2
2020-01-01 10:00:00      2
```

What allows the latter two examples to work?  I can see maybe they are a little more explicit (*"Please, I really want to resample this column!"*), but I don't see why the original `resample` doesn't allow the operation if it can be done.

Comment: I'm fiding pandas groupby.resample.agg('last') also changes booleans to floats on ver 1.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, tracking down shows that:

```
df.resample('5H')['Bools'].sum == Groupby.sum (in pd.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy)
```

```
df.resample('5H').sum == sum (in pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler)
```

and tracking `groupby_function` in [groupby.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.5/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py) shows that it's equivalent to
`r.agg(lambda x: np.sum(x, axis=r.axis))`
where `r = df.resample('5H')`  which outputs:

```
                     Bools  Nums  Nums2
2020-01-01 05:00:00      2    10     10
2020-01-01 10:00:00      2    35     35
```

*well, actually, it should've been `r = df.resample('5H')['Bool']` (only for the case above)*

and tracking down the `_downsample` function in [resample.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.5/pandas/core/resample.py) shows that it's equivalent to:
`df.groupby(r.grouper, axis=r.axis).agg(np.sum)` which outputs:

```
                     Nums  Nums2
2020-01-01 05:00:00    10     10
2020-01-01 10:00:00    35     35
```

Comment: Interesting!  I guess these do boil down to slightly different things, thanks for tracking that down

Comment: Yes, I feared the distinction would be mere tautological (it still kinda feels like it is!) - but, the `lambda` there forces addition for each of the columns individually which the other version doesn't (`.agg(np.sum, axis=0)` does though)

Answer (score 0):

`df.resample('5H').sum()` doesn't work on `Bools` column because the column has mixed data type, which is `object` in pandas. When calling `sum()` on `resample` or `groupby`, `object` typed columns will be ignored.

Comment: Yes, but I was more wondering why you can do `df.resample('5H')['Bools'].sum()` or `df.drop(['Nums'],axis=1).resample('5H').sum()`. The data are still type `object` in these cases, no?

Comment: There might be a flag somewhere to check if **all** columns are of `object` type. In which case, `sum` is forced on all columns, which also works on `list` type. So `df.astype('object').resample('5H').sum()` would just work as well.

Comment: I didn't know that would work, and would explain why the `drop` version works.  Thanks for sharing this